# Sandboxd Deny network-bind error message when binds socket

Tags: sandbox

I have developed webkit based application and sandboxed the application. But after sandboxing the same, I could not load webpages in the application. The webpages are crashing. Here is the error message ..

sandboxd : Deny network-bind [application support folder path]

Anyone faced such an issue? Not sure what entitlement key and value need to be given to resovle this issue.

Comment: I am using chromium code base.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem, and after a while I found that sandbox don't allow to bind, on a socket created outside the app container.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, though not with WebKit but with a Qt application using a `QTcpServer` instance listening on the local host.

You need to add the `com.apple.security.network.server` entitlement to your application's manifest. It's documented in Apple's [Entitlement Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#).